¿Cómo puedo conectar mi aplicación de Android Studio a una base de datos con PHP?
Tengo creada una aplicación en Android Studio y tengo una base de datos que HostGator me dió por contratar sus servicios.
Seguí un tutorial en YouTube para conectar mi aplicación a mi base de datos teniendo dos archivos PHP como intermediarios. Pero el ejemplo tenía su base de datos en localhost (porque usó XAMPP). En cierta parte del procedimiento debo especificar la ruta de mis archivos PHP, pero tengo la duda sobre cómo debo subirlos, o si debo seguir un diferentes pasos al tener mi base de datos en línea.
Este es el archivo PHP #1 - conexion.php
Cabe señalar que los datos de IP, usuario, contraseña, y la base de datos son correctos, porque antes de intentar conectarme a mi BD desde Android creé un pequeño código en NetBeans con Java para ver si los datos que enviaría fueran los correctos, y desde mi aplicación de Java/netbeans en PC puedo ver mis datos de mi BD sin problemas:
<?php

$hostname = 'aqui_esta_mi_ip';

$database = 'nombre_de_mi_bd';
$username = 'mi_usuario';
$password = 'mi_contra';

$conexion = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if($conexion->connect_errno) { echo 'Error'; }
else { echo 'Completado'; }

?>

Archivo Php #2:agregar_cita.php
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$hora = $_POST['hora'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

$consulta = "INSERT INTO Citas (bd_nombre, bd_numero, bd_fecha, bd_hora_cita, bd_mensaje) VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$numero."', '".$fecha."', '".$hora."', '".$mensaje."');";
mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>

.
Aquí está una sección de código que está en mi activity_main.java de mi app de android.
Aquí es donde tengo duda sobre la ubicación de mis archivos PHP, porque no sé si esos archivos se deben quedar dentro de mi APP de Android Studio, (osea que esos archivos PHP estén junto los archivos de activity_main.JAVA y los demás archivos), o si los archivos PHP se deben subir a la red, aunque no sé en dónde o cómo se sube, no sé si se usa PHPmyAdmin o algún otro recurso o herramienta de CPanel, o alguna otra forma:
nombre1 = findViewById(R.id.nombre_b);
        numero1 = findViewById(R.id.numero_b);
        fecha1 = findViewById(R.id.fecha_b);
        hora1 = findViewById(R.id.hora_b);
        mensaje1 = findViewById(R.id.mensaje_b);

        clickear = findViewById(R.id.boton_insertar);

        clickear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ejecutarServicio("aqui_tengo_duda_sobre_qué_poner");
            }
        });

Y este código está también en mi activity_main.java:
private void ejecutarServicio (String URL)
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sin problemas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
            {
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("bd_nombre", nombre1.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("bd_numero", numero1.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("bd_fecha", fecha1.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("bd_hora", hora1.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("bd_mensaje", mensaje1.getText().toString());
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

.
Anteriormente observé que este tipo de conexión es complejo, porque observé que no se puede conectar mi App de Android Studio directamente con mi BD por temas de seguridad, por eso opté por seguir los pasos para conectarse usando PHP, pero tengo esta duda, no sé si esté omitiendo algún dato muy obvio, o algo parecido.
También cabe mencionar que en mi AndroidManifest.xml ya habilité los permisos para usar internet. Así mismo agregué a mi build.gradle el siguiente código:
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

.

No pienses "tengo que conectar mi android a mysql" porque eso NO es lo que estás haciendo. Estás intentando consumir un servicio http como cualquier otro. Busca un tutorial sobre cómo usar volley para hacer una llamada GET o POST, que es lo único que tienes que hacer para llamar a tu código PHP. Aprender a llamar a las cosas por su nombre es importante, si buscas cómo conectar android a mysql no vas a encontrar la solución, si buscas cómo consumir un servicio web o cómo hacer una llamada GET o POST con volley, hay millones de ejemplos. Aquí solo podemos ayudarte con algo concreto, no esto.

Para hacerlo breve. 1. En el servidor remoto tienes que crear una API o Servicio Web con unas URLs definidas para los diferentes recursos que quieres exponer; 2. En Android, haces una petición a cualquiera de esas URLs requiriendo o enviando los datos, según quieras consultar datos o modificarlos. Puedes usar Volley, como haces ahora, o Retrofit en un futuro. Este último es más fácil si quieres escribir una App basada en Clean Architecture. Es un tema amplio, y medianamente avanzado. Te recomendaría empezar haciendo pruebas con una API pública que sea gratis ...

... para entender cómo funciona. Y cuando hagas funcionar ese código entonces puedes programar tu propia API en tu servidor. Los datos pueden estar en MySql o cualquier SGBD. Otra cosa, phpMyAdmin no tiene nada que ver aquí, es solo una interfaz gráfica para interactuar con la base de datos.

El PHP va en el servidor, lo subes desde el CPanel o desde un FTP. Luego para probar que funcionen correctamente usas POSTMAN (o similar). Cuando todo funciones, pasas a probarlo en android
